# prepare react native for release

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have my old app which was built using cordova and published on app store 1 year ago.

Its id is : com.simpleinformatics.app and current version on app store and google play stores is 2.2.1

Now that we decided to rewrite app but this time using "react native", new app is now finished and tested on android and ios in debug mode

***I want to publish it android and apple stores as an update for old cordova app.***

What are the correct steps to do so ?

I tried changing provision profile and bundler id in xcode but that result in a new .xcode file and for android it looks like just updating androidmanifest is not enough. After playing with manifest for android and xcode project suddenly project is failing to build.

Can some one point us to a guild on how to brand react native app before preparing to publish so that app store would accept it as update for old cordova app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the react-native version you are using there are bunch of files that have to be changed on both platforms (android and ios)

### List of files to edit:

### IOS

1. *[application_build_scheem]*.plist (this is a dict/xml file that contains keys that are used by default **if no changes** added to project (react-native-cli init type of project)

### ANDROID

1. strings.xml (change *app_name* key value)
2. manifest.xml (change *package* attribute)
3. build.gradle (change *applicationId* value)
4. MainActivity.java (change java class *package*)
5. MainApplication.java (change java class *package*)

### Worth mentioning:

there is an an npm module @ https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ci-tools, it happens to do all of the above use it and make life easy.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS you need to change the `bundle` in Xcode (just tap on your project). On Android you need to change the bundle in `AndroidManifest` and in your `build.gradle`.